# IFRAME sandbox attribute is blocking AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, html, iframe, sandbox, same-origin-policy

I have an application (`http://localhost/MyApp`), where some of the parts are rendered through IFRAMES. These iframed parts has no business with the rest of the application's DOM, so I applied the `sandbox` attribute.

The IFRAME is declared like this:

```
<iframe src="/MyApp/en/html/action?id=1" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
```

The iframed page has a button that makes a AJAX call to the same web application, but then rather than a `HTTP GET`, the browser issues a `HTTP OPTIONS` that appears as `Cancelled`, and an error happens:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/MyApp/en/data/action?id=1. Cannot make any requests from null.
Ajax State 0 Error: HTTP 0
```

If I add the `allow-same-origin` to the `sandbox` attribute, it works.As far as [I read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx), it was not supposed to affect AJAX calls.

Why is this happening? Is considering the path `/MyApp/en/html/action` as origin of the whole IFRAME and blocking the request to previous levels?

Cheers.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes article. It is a nice explanation of the sandbox attribute.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The reason it affects Ajax is because Ajax is governed by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) rules, and when you sandbox it you're effectively telling the browser to treat the `iframe` contents as if it were from a different origin. Quoting the same [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx):

> - **Unique origin treatment.** All content is treated under a unique origin. The content is not able to traverse the DOM or read cookie information.
>
> This means that even content coming from the same domain is treated with the cross-domain policy, as each *IFRAME* content will be viewed as a unique origin.
>
> **Embedded content is only permitted to display information.** No other actions can be done inside the *IFRAME* that could compromise the hosting website or take advantage of the users’ trust.

In other words, if you omit the `allow-same-origin` in the `sandbox` attribute, it will treat the sandboxed page as belonging to a different domain (in fact, it will treat as having a `null` origin). Since it doesn't make sense to make Ajax requests to `null`, sandboxed pages can not make Ajax calls at all (if making them to `localhost` were allowed they would be indistinguishable from the calls from the parent page, defeating the purpose of sandboxing).

#### Additional info

If you try to make an Ajax call to a different domain, it will obviously fail:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log(location.host);
    $.post('https://google.com/',{},function() { });
</script>
```

However, **how** it will fail will depend on the sandbox attribute used. If you embed the page above in an `iframe` with `allow-same-origin` it will print this to the console:

```
localhost
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://google.com/. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

...and if you embed it **without** `allow-same-origin`:

```
localhost
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://google.com/. Cannot make any requests from null.
```

Note that, while both reported `location.host` as `localhost`, one considered the origin to be `http://localhost` while the other considered it to be `null` (showing the same error message you experienced in your example).

#### Reasoning

Why is it so important to block Ajax calls from sandboxed contents from the same domain? As explained in the article:

> It kind of makes sense that content on the same domain *should* be safe. The risk here primarily stems from user-generated content that is re-hosted in the *IFRAME*.

Let's make up an example: suppose Facebook decides to allow users post little HTML5 animations in their pages. It stores them in its own servers and, when displaying, sandboxes them as `allow-scripts` only (because scripts are needed for the animations to work) but leave everything else denied (in particular `allow-same-origin`, since you don't want user code messing up with the parent page). What would happen if Ajax calls weren't also blocked by default?

Mallory creates an "animation" that consists of:

1. Performing an Ajax call to Facebook, using its API (say, [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/tipsandtricks/)); the server will happily accept the call, since for all it knows the request came from a page with `https://facebook.com` as origin.
2. Create a URI pointing to her own server, with the returned data as query strings, and set it as the `src` of a picture in the sandboxed page.

When Alice visits Mallory profile, and sees the animation, the script above runs:

1. The Ajax call runs in Alice's browser, while Alice is logged on; since the server does not know where the call comes from (main page or embedded page) it will do whatever it's asked to - including retrieving personal info.
2. When the `img` element is created with Mallory's URI, the browser will attempt to load the "image" normally, since images are exempt from the Same Origin Policy.
3. Since the URI has Alice's private info in the query string, Mallory's server can just save it and return whatever image it wants. Now Mallory has Alice's personal info, and Alice suspects nothing.

Comment: So you mean that because parent frame is using host A, even if the child frame is using also host A as origin, it will be unable of perform AJAX to their own origin because the parent frame is using it? That sounds like a wacky implementation, the browser should know which calls is doing each iframe.

Comment: The browser does, but what about the server? If the server did not explicitly grant same origin privileges to the sandboxed page, how do you know that it's expecting to receive Ajax calls from it? What if your server is a [cajoling server](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/), and the code running in the `iframe` comes from an untrusted third-party? The domain they're running on will be the same, but that doesn't mean the third-party code should have the capability to make Ajax calls to the server (potentially leaking sensitive info). IMHO that's the correct design, security-wise.

Comment: The server should not care where the request is coming from. Actually who is blocking the request is the browser not the server. Sorry, it is that this issue looks a little bit strange to me.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. The whole point of sandboxing is to deny everything that wasn't explicitly allowed. Since the browser doesn't know what the server cares and what not, it should err on the safe side, and assume Ajax calls (and well as other same origin privileges) are **not** ok. If you wanna accept Ajax from the sandboxed content, but not let it mess up with the parent page, I'm afraid you'll need another strategy, like [postMessage](http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-window-messaging-with-html-5-postmessage) or [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

Comment: But... Did you notice that in my scenario both the page and the iframe are pointing to the same host and application?

Comment: Look, I totally agree with you that confounding "access to parent page" and "ajax to the same domain" was a a bad idea. And disallowing sandboxed code to do **any** ajax was a terrible idea (that could be useful in many cases, with CORS). But I'm not a security expert, so I don't know what the designers behind iframe sandboxing had in mind. Trust is a hairy business.. You say "These iframed parts has no business with the rest of the application's DOM", but what does that mean? That they're **untrusted** in that regard? What makes them **trusted** with ajax but not with the parent page's DOM?

Comment: I would like to point out, that adding the allow-same-origin tag to the sandbox attribute actually DOES NOT make a foreign origin to be handled as the same origin. It only makes the browser to handle this iframe as a normal iframe would be handled by the same origin policy. So if you apply this attribute to a foreign domain page, it would still not be able to access the DOM of your main page. Only if you apply it to a url on the same domain (or any other domain allowed by domain policy headers), the page would be able to access your DOM or make AJAX requests to your domain.