# Is there any way to sandbox some javascript so that it can not in any way send data to a server

Tags: javascript, sandbox

The purpose for this is to run some user created JavaScript that processes sensitive data that should not escape the sandbox. My purpose here is to not only sandbox the script that is running, but to also sandbox the data that it is processing.

I can set up a sub domain or a web worker and use sendMessage to run the script and post the results back to the parent. I could use the new html5 sandbox flag on an iframe. All three of these methods can be used to isolate the script from the parent domain, but I can't find a way of locking down a script so that it can't send data to a server.

For example a script running on web worker could use an ajax request with a server that accepts cross domain requests to break the data out of the sandbox.

Comment: I dont really understand, what you want to do? What scenario are you trying to prevent? can you give some details?

Comment: @winner_joiner I've edited the question. I want to sandbox the data that the script is processing as well as the scripts access to the main program. This means the script must not be able to pass the data to a third party server.

Comment: Redefine `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send` function to something like `return false`, if you are talking about AJAX requests from script.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev That is a good idea. Does is it work across all browsers?

Comment: Using Web Worker it's a good start: they can't do any DOM trick, the only way to do a server request is via `Web Socket`, `WebRTC` and `XMLHttpRequest`. If you override those things, and you're sure they can't obtain them from other window's reference, you should be fine.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev According to PinalThis method will not work, you can just run delete window.XMLHttpRequest and the native functionality is returned.

Comment: In legacy IE versions its something like `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP").prototype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cut off any native transport for script.

For example, Worker has access only to one native transport XMLHttpRequest(because no access to document -> no node with src, link, forms ) and you can redefine it ie `window.XMLHttpRequest = function () {return 1}` and script can't send data to server.

But just run `delete window.XMLHttpRequest` and you will set back native XMLHttpRequest. It works fine and in strict mode (ECMAScript-262 ed. 5/6)

`(function () {`

`'use strict';`

`window.XMLHttpRequest = function () {return 1};`

`console.log(window.XMLHttpRequest);`

`delete window.XMLHttpRequest;`

`console.log(window.XMLHttpRequest);`

`})()`

About HTML5 iframe options. If you use `sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-pointer-lock"` any script from iframe can't send cross-domain requests(XMLHttpRequest,postMessage,WebSocket, WebRTC, Server-Sent Events...any). If you need to denied cross-domain request - that is it.

Comment: Are you saying that sandbox does prevent all server requests by default? When I tested in with firebug it looked like it was still sending the request, but on further testing it does not seem to be reaching the server. Would be great if you could point to the documentation for this behavior

Comment: No worries, found extra details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486461/iframe-sandbox-attribute-is-blocking-ajax-calls

Comment: No I say that sandbox attribute with same-origin policy prevent all cross-domain requests. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) for more information.

Comment: Just discovered a flaw in this method. Data can leak through by including content such as an image and placing data on the url. However if I combine this with a webworker to remove access to the DOM then it should work.

Comment: Yes. But, it's impossible :(