# Header not being set for OPTIONS Ajax request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis-7, get, access-control

I have an `ascx` page `GetToken.ashx`.

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    context.Response.Write(Token.CreateToken());
}
```

When I AJAX to this page, it returns the following headers:

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:36
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 14 Apr 2015 17:20:53 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

When the page that makes the AJAX request is placed in a sandboxed iFrame, it shows the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://127.0.0.1:112/handlers/gettoken.ashx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

And returns the headers:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Allow:OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Content-Length:0
Date:Tue, 14 Apr 2015 17:30:14 GMT
Public:OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

I cannot seem to get the `OPTIONS` request to add the header.  Adding `allow-same-origin` to the sandbox properties changes the request to a `GET`, but I do not wish to grant the iFrame those permissions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you meant to write `ashx`, not `ascx`. The presence of the `ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)` method suggests it's a generic handler and not a user control.

I've made a very simple page to test with:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testCorsDiv">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Handler/testCors.ashx",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (theData) { $("#testCorsDiv").text(theData); },
            error: function (theData) { alert('error'); }
        });
    </script>
    <% if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["sandboxed"])) { %>
    <iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:49253/SandboxTest.aspx?sandboxed=true" sandbox="allow-scripts" width="600">
    </iframe>
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

I load the page on `http://localhost:49253/SandboxTest.aspx`. The page then makes an `ajax` request to `http://localhost:49253/Handler/testCors.ashx` and puts the output from that into the `testCorsDiv` div. This generates a straight `GET` to the handler (since it's coming from the same origin) and the output gets inserted.

In the page is also a sandboxed `iframe` which loads the same page using the url `http://127.0.0.1:49253/SandboxTest.aspx`. The `?sandboxed=true` is there to prevent the iframe from recursively loading an inner iframe. The page loaded in the iframe will then try to make an ajax request to `http://127.0.0.1:49253/Handler/testCors.ashx` and display the output in it's own copy of the `testCorsDiv` div.

As long as the sandboxed iframe has `allow-scripts` this works like a charm. The `iframe` generates an `OPTIONS` request looking like this (from Fiddler, tested with Chrome):

```
OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:49253/Handler/testCors.ashx HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:49253
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90     Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, x-requested-with
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:49253/SandboxTest.aspx?sandboxed=true
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: fi-FI,fi;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

My `testCors.ashx` handler then spits out some headers that says that this looks ay-ok and the browser then follows up with a `GET` and it just works.

The `testCors.ashx` does this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type, x-requested-with, accept");
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET");
    context.Response.Write("Hello World");
}
```

So my testing suggests that it should be possible to do what you want. One thing though that might be an issue is if your handler is only accessible to authenticated/authorized users. As you can see the `OPTIONS` request has not sent a cookie to the handler. But on the other hand your question says that the response to you options request is `Status Code:200`. I suppose that would be some `4**` if a required authentication cookie was missing.

Wrapping up, I don't really know what's wrong in your case, but maybe (?) my simple sample page can give you some clues that will help you find the issue yourself.

Comment: Thank you, using your example I managed to recreate the problem simply, and then with some tweaking got it working!

Comment: @TomGullen Glad that my answer was of help. And thanks for the bounty, appreciate it even if I'm not sure that I deserved it since I didn't really solve your problem...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have IIS setting to allow `OPTION` to that handler - deployed to app having say App pool name "web-app" and corresponding handler mapping should allow `OPTION` request.

Following are the steps to do that.

- select required app pool
- Click on handler mappings
- select *.ashx and double click on the corresponding handler , click on Request Restriction , see if you have option verb there, if not, add that.

Above mentioned here - http://www.chrisweldon.net/blog/2012/04/13/jquery-file-uploader/

You may need to use following code.

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    // You can try adding requested origin here instead of * like this - Request.Headers["Origin"] or only the specific domain, in your case it is -https://127.0.0.1:112
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
    }
    context.Response.Write(Token.CreateToken());
}
```

I have explained this in [my blog](https://arindamnayak1.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/enabling-cors-in-wcf/). This was for WCF, but it should work for your case too! You might need to change `*` for allowed origin to requested origin, as * has security issue, it allows all domains to make CORS call.

Comment: All my ASHX handlers have the OPTION verb, and I've used the code above.  It's still not working!  `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: This might be a silly suggestion, can you try adding `null` in place of `*` ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the below code in **both of your HTML and iFrame page** (in the HTML DOC) and check if it works?

```
<script>document.domain = 'myDomain.com'</script>
```

Note: Please replace the 'myDomain' with appropriate domain name of the domain you are using (the origin)

Answer (score 0):

Making AJAX requests appears to be absolutely impossible from a sandboxed iframe without the `allow-same-origin` option.

See this answer for a detailed explanation: [IFRAME sandbox attribute is blocking AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486461/iframe-sandbox-attribute-is-blocking-ajax-calls)

However, I'm not quite convinced about it. Before giving up, make sure that your server accepts AJAX requests from a different hostname without sandboxing (ie. if it supports CORS).

For more info about CORS see: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 0):

The error your are getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://127.0.0.1:112/handlers/gettoken.ashx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

is because your application have been secured from the clickjacking attacks. In your case `X-Fame-Options` in your application web.config is probably set to `Deny`, setting it to 'SAMEORIGIN' would help fix your problem, provided you have your application has the same domain as your `iframe`.

This is how its done:

```
<system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

If you are able find a work around for this (I mean make your application work in iframe with Deny option set), then it would defeat the sole purpose (security against clickjacking) of having such a feature.

Hope this helps.